# How to get the selected values from a checkbox reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a number string values of array. I am about to retrieve the list of selected checkbox dynamically.

```
 const arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
 
 function App() {
   // holds the list of items selected by the user when a form is submitted
   const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

   const handleCheckbox= (e) => {
      // codes here
   }

   const Options = arr.map(item => {
       return <input type='checkbox' value={item} onChange={handleCheckbox} />
   });

   return (
     <form>
       <Options />
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
   )
 }
```

How can I get the values of checkbox selected by the user on form submission?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the handleCheckbox function to update the selected state whenever a checkbox is checked or unchecked. Then, when the form is submitted, you can access the selected values from the selected state.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
const arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
 
function App() {
  // holds the list of items selected by the user when a form is submitted
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const handleCheckbox = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setSelected([...selected, value]); // add the value to the selected array
    } else {
      setSelected(selected.filter(item => item !== value)); // remove the value from the selected array
    }
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(selected); // access the selected values from the state
  }

  const Options = arr.map(item => {
    return <input key={item} type='checkbox' value={item} onChange={handleCheckbox} />
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {Options}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

In the handleCheckbox function, we check whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked, and update the selected state accordingly. We use the spread operator (...) to create a new array with the added value when a checkbox is checked, and use the filter method to remove the value when a checkbox is unchecked.

In the handleSubmit function, we log the selected values to the console. You can modify this code to do whatever you need with the selected values.